# Недопустимое значение свойства в медиа-запросе

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, адаптивная-верстка

Возможно ли использовать VW единиц в медиа-запросе?

ошибка в width

вот мой код:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1640px)
.hotstringscont {
    width: calc(1300px +((100vw - 1300px) / 2));
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 68px) 0, calc(100% - 188px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Comment: Нужно поставить пробел после "+"